# True or False: Endocytosis delivers vesicles directly to the cis face of the Golgi complex

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, homework

Does anyone know the answer to this question, and also the explanation of to why this is True or False?

I know that Endocytosis is the process of uptake of materials into cells including microorganisms, solute particles, and food particles from the ECF. The Golgi Complex is the trafficking directory organelle of the cell which vesicles enter in the cis face and exit in the 'rougher' trans face. It adds tags to vesicles for target compartments. Proteins come from the rER wrapped in vesicles and directed to the Golgi Complex.

In my knowledge the membrane bound or secreted proteins are directed to the rER first, thus I am half certain that this question's answer is False.

Comment: I've added the [tag:homework] tag to your question, since that seems appropriate (even if the question you got was not meant as homework). However, I do think you're providing your own thoughts and tenative answer on the question, so I don't understand the close votes.